# Need to export the output to an csv

Tags: powershell, active-directory, export-to-csv

Im trying to run the below code that compares the user and group and confirms if the user is a member of the group. But i'm unable to export the output to an excel.

```
    $users = gc .\UserInfo.csv
    $groups = gc .\groupInfo.csv
    $outputFilePath = "C:\Users\salesid.csv"

$members = foreach ($group in $groups) {Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive | Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

foreach ($user in $users) {
If ($members -contains $user) {
     $a = write-host "$user is a member of $group"
} Else {
   $a = Write-Host "$user is not a member of $group"
}
}
}

    $a| Export-Csv .\Output.csv -NoTypeInformation
    Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To output as CSV file you can open in Excel, you need to output **objects** in the loop, not strings:

```
$users          = Get-Content .\UserInfo.csv
$groups         = Get-Content .\groupInfo.csv
$outputFilePath = "C:\Users\salesid.csv"

# loop through the groups; collect all output in $result
$result = foreach ($group in $groups) {
    $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
    # loop through the users array and outout objects that get collected in variable $result
    foreach ($user in $users) {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            Group    = $group
            User     = $user
            IsMember = ($members -contains $user)  # True or False in the output
        }
    }
}

$result | Export-Csv -Path $outputFilePath -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

---

If the amount of data is too large to handle in memory, the following code should work, BUT will be slower because of all the extra disk-write actions:

```
# loop through the groups
foreach ($group in $groups) {
    $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName -Unique
    # loop through the users array and outout objects that get collected in variable $result
    foreach ($user in $users) {
        $isMember = "$user is {0}a member of $group" -f $(if ($members -contains $user) {''} else {'NOT '})
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            Group    = $group
            User     = $user
            IsMember = $isMember
        } | Export-Csv -Path $outputFilePath -UseCulture -Append -NoTypeInformation
    }
}
```

<sup>switch `-UseCulture` makes sure the delimiter character is the same **your** local Excel will understand. This might be the default comma, but perhaps your system uses the semi-colon as list seoarator</sup>

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly.Is it possible to have output like "user is a member of group" instead of True or false ?

Comment: @ScriptingisLife Sure, you can put anything you like in the PsCustomObject, like `IsMember = "$user is {0}a member of $group" -f $(if ($members -contains $user) {''} else {'NOT '})` or something. Just remember to output **objects**, not just strings in order to get a real CSV file

Comment: the issue im facing here is the script is unable to handle large data!!any suggestions

Comment: @ScriptingisLife Please see my edit. If it is the .csv file that is too large to fit in memory (BTW. it isn't really a csv, but just a list of usernames each on its own line) you need to break that up into several smaller files and re-run the code for those parts.

Comment: @ScriptingisLife Sorry, I meant the **input** csv files are in fact textfiles with one item each on a separate line. The **output** file is a valid csv with headers.